# Rails3 - access to controller create method from not 'new' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller **vegetable**. It has standart *new* and *create* methods.

I want to create **potato** action, that contain form and using vegetable's *create* method.

In **potato** view i have this:

```
= form_for @vegetable, :url => '/vegetable/create/' do |f|
  = f.text_field :color
  = f.submit "Save"
```

When i press save, i get error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in VegetablesController#update  
Couldn't find Vegetable with ID=create
```

It uses `update`, not `create` method. How can i say Rails to send form to `create` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you sould use corresponded **:url => vegetable_path**